# Unable to use tailwind headless ui with vue 2 .Object(...) is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to do insert headless ui popover in my vue 2 project . I am having this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (headlessui.esm.js?d511:670)
    at Module../node_modules/@headlessui/vue/dist/headlessui.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Navigations/Navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:5)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Navigations/Navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:998)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Navbar.vue?7538:1)
    at Module../src/components/Navigations/Navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:2161)
```

my code looks like this .

```
  <div v-if="isLoggedIn" class="flex space-x-2">
      <NotificationCenter />
      <Popover class="relative">
    <PopoverButton>Solutions</PopoverButton>

    <PopoverPanel class="absolute z-10">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
        <a href="/analytics">Analytics</a>
        <a href="/engagement">Engagement</a>
        <a href="/security">Security</a>
        <a href="/integrations">Integrations</a>
      </div>
    </PopoverPanel>
  </Popover>
    </div>
```

inside script i have imported and added the components as usual .

```
import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel } from '@headlessui/vue'
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    MenuButton,
    UserStats,
    NotificationCenter,
    Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel
  },
```

Answer (score 12):

check the docs

"Please note that this library only supports Vue 3."

https://headlessui.dev/vue/popover

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. Thanks @KeithNicholas